# Generar PDF con Paper Height dinámico

Tags: genexus, genexus18

Necesito crear un pdf para una impresora de rollo. El problema que me encuentro es que al definir el reporte debo indicarle el height. Intenté generar varias hojas pero la app que termina imprimiendo (en Android) únicamente imprime la primer hoja.

Estoy utilizando Gx18 generando .net framework.